# EntityFieldQuery vs Db_select()

Tags: 7, entities

Why should I use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) when I can do the same work with [Db_select()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) to fetch the value.

It would be better if someone can provide an example, not only a link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the point is that the syntax is much simpler, and the code will be more understandable.

For example, if you want nodes with type `my_type` that have a field named `field_foo` with the value `$val`, with Db_Select, yuoll do something like :

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->join('field_data_field_foo', 'foo', 'foo.entity_id = n.nid')
  ->condition('n.type', 'my_type')
  ->condition('foo.field_foo_value', $val)
  ->execute()->fetchCol();
```

Which is much simpler with EntityFieldQuery :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_type')
  ->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', $val)
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 14):

I think that the main reason prefering `EntityFieldQuery` over `db_select` is that you don't have to know about the lower-level structure, in other words: how stuff is stored in the database. This improves [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Comment: This is correct, although it goes even further. The field storage is pluggable. The default implementation stores field data in a separate table per field in the database, but it can be replaced, there is for example an implementation which allows to store field data in MongoDB. If you want your code to be portable and not just work on your specific site configuration, you must use EntityFieldQuery.

Answer (score 3):

EntityFieldQuery (EFQ) will only return entity IDs. If you want to access entities data, you'll have to call `entity_load()`, which, among loading the data, will make sure that all underlying stuff you normally do not care about (such as loading fields, calling other modules hooks etc.) are made. Of course, this result in **two** SQL queries and a lot of overhead, but this is the price to pay for the abstraction.

As for the EFQ syntax being more clear, I think it's much more a question of personal preferences. I, for instance, do **not** think that EFQ is clearer. Notice that a working `db_select()` replacement with EFQ must include the return value test and subsequent `entity_load()` call, and this adds a lot of noise to the code, IMHO:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_type')
  ->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', $val)
  ->execute();
if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
  $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));
} else {
  $nodes = array();
}
```

So, answering your question: use EFQ if your entities are full-featured (e.g. are fieldable, can be used by other modules, etc.) and/or you think that its syntax is clearer. If other cases, use may use `db_select()`.

Comment: Not exactly, you can use entity_metadata_wrapper and access only what you need.

Comment: I fail to see how `entity_metadata_wrapper()` helps here. You still need to load the entity.

Answer (score 1):

*EntityFieldQuery* is far more limited than *`db_select()`*, so you should have a really good reason to not use *`db_select()`* (see bart answer), which is readable enough and far more flexible.

For example, `entityFieldQuery` use *innerJoin* to fetch fields. If you need a leftJoin for whatever reason, you're trapped...
http://drupal.org/node/1226622

Comment: Well, I would like to know why my anwser had a "-1". yeah, entityFieldQuery is prettier, but less efficient than db_select that is a very nice, robust and complete API... I remove a lot of my entityFieldQuery from my code because it was too limited for specific use cases, think it definitely deserved to be pointed out. Anyway.

Comment: I think some don't like your answer because it fails to acknowledge how entityFieldQuery is an abstraction layer above different storage methods, which is a cool feature. I work on lots of sites where we know that, say, MySQL will always be the database for x/y/z and we also prefer to write leaner db queries when we need to. I don't find entityFieldQuery to be any prettier than db_select. The 2 comparisons at the top of the page are nearly visually identical.

Comment: yep, that's why i wrote "see bart answer". Except for this special use-case, db_select will be more efficient and far more flexible.

Comment: I completely agree.