# Which method has better performance

Tags: nodes, entities, performance

I want to update some term id on some node (let suppose 1000 node),My changes is convert all `news node with category(term_id) = 3040 to category(term_id)=5)`.

I know I can do it with several methods( use views bulk operation, write batch running etc, .... ) but my question is about performance of below approaches

1. Approach based on old method ( node_save)

   ```
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
   $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
           ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
           ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
           ->fieldCondition('field_category', 'tid', array('3040'));
   $result = $query->execute();
   $nids= array_keys($result['node']);
   //ym($nids);

   $nodes= node_load_multiple($nids);
   foreach ($nodes as $node){
       foreach($node->field_category['und'] as $i=>$item){
          if($item['tid']==3040){
               $node->field_category['und'][$i]['tid']=5;
               node_save($node);
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Approach based on entity wrapper method

   ```
       $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
       $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
               ->entityCondition('bundle', 'news')
               ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
               ->fieldCondition('field_category', 'tid', array('3040'));
       $result = $query->execute();
   foreach($result['node'] as $nid => $stub_node) {
     // Load the full node and wrap it with entity_metadata_wrapper().
     $node = node_load($nid);
     $wrapped_node = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $node);
     if ($wrapped_node->field_category->value()->tid == 3040) {
       $wrapped_node->field_category->tid->set(5);
       $wrapped_node->save();
     }
   ```

in first approach we have one `node_load` and one `node_save` but in second approach we have one `node_load` one creating entity metawrapper creation and one entity wrapper save.
**I want to know which method has better performance?**
*let suppose we have the same situation for both 2 method, I just want somebody tell me ( take a benchmark on one node and  in bulk ( multi node) mode and tell me the performance of both that which one of this method is faster in the same situation.*
please provide your answer with facts or benchmark testing result

Comment: Rolled back to original question - please don't substantially change questions once they've been answered. Thanks

Comment: @Clive I have a mistake in question, load node multiple and one by one and it make my question to suitable,So I change my question to manner that the situation on loading be same and with this manner others can has better answers,What is your idea Master Clive, Do u think which method is faster?

Comment: You need to run the benchmarks yourself, it's very unlikely you'll convince someone to do that work for you. It would be pointless anyway, an answer could only make sense if a benchmark was run on the exact environment the site in question is running on. Then it comes down to what modules are installed, how everything is configured, and what resources are available. On shared hosting it would be even more impossible to predict, and probably even more pointless to try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research and some benchmark  I get below results

**In equal and regular situation** using Entity Meta Wrapper for change the node fileds has better performance.

> Loading the entity object just for passing into EMW. Unless you
>   already have the pre-populated entity, it's more efficient to just
>   pass the entity id to entity_metadata_wrapper(); EMW will lazy load
>   the field and property data that it needs, hoorah! So much magic.

(if we have $node it is better use it but if we don't have it **Don't use node_load to load it before pass it to entity_metadata_wrapper and just pass nid to it has better performance rather first load node then pass it to EMW**

```
// Unnecessary node load... $node = node_load($nid); 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node); // More efficient       
(if the object isn't handed to you)... 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)
```

Saving the entity with node_save(), taxonomy_term_save(), etc. instead of the EMW save() method. Fun fact: both EMW and standard entity controllers include save() methods, so you can call e.g. $node->save() on properly instantiated entity objects and wrappers.

```
// If you don't already have the node object, don't bother loading it just to save... 
$wrapper->field_foobar = 'new value'; 
$node = $wrapper->value(); 
node_save($node); // Easier and prettier... 
$wrapper->field_foobar = 'new value';
$wrapper->save();
```

Reference: [Death to Field Arrays](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper)

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially impossible to answer.  You have one part of your question, wrong

- Your first method uses a single `node_load_multiple()` with multiple `node_save`
- Your second answer uses multiple `node_load()` with multiple Entity API calls

My *gut* tells me the first will be quicker, as a single `node_load_multiple()` is typically more performant than multiple `node_load()` calls, given the same set of nodes.  You also aren't creating the the metadata wrapper objects.

However, you need to do the benchmarking on your system.  There may be a difference, but it may be small enough to not make a real imapact.  Some things that make cross-system benchmarks unreliable

- entitycache can have a tremendous impact on a system, especially if you use a non-SQL backend for it
- the number of fields on your node can effect how long the wrapper creation process takes, and also how long the `node_save()` takes
- APC and/or OpCache usage and configuration
- PHP version
- MySQL configuration (or whatever database backend you are using), including some of the Drupal-specific tricks that can improve performance
- The number of `hook_node_update()` instances that fire for each save

Comment: ok, I change my question that both use one method and strategy.

Comment: I update my question and make it easier to answer about it.

Comment: Normally, a substantial edit to a question like this after answers isn't really allowed.  I will let another moderator make the call here since one of the answers is mine.  However, my answer stands.  There are too many other factors at play.  You need to benchmark this on your system to see how much of a difference this makes.

Comment: I am sorry about make some change in my question, it because  I found there is not the same situation, tnx for your attention, but I ask, if we suppose we are in a common shared host with default and equal situation which method is fast.

Comment: As far as I understand, EntityMetadataWrapper::save() somewhere eventually just calls `node_save()` anyways, but the additional memory and CPU overhead of using the entity wrapper is probably not significant for most use cases.  If you are hitting timeout or memory limits, it would be best to use Batch API.

Answer (score 3):

Given that performance is an issue you may alter the code of your first approach (1) like this :

```
$field_name = 'field_category';
$tid = '3040';
$nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} n, field_data_{$field_name} c WHERE n.nid = c.entity_id AND c.bundle = 'blog_post' AND c.{$field_name}_tid = :tid", array(':tid' => $tid))->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] == 3040) {
    $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = 5;
    field_attach_update('node', $node); // Instead of node_load
  }
}
```

What I did was to (1) change the use of [EntityFieldQuery()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) with [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) by the time it is [much faster](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129669/whats-faster-db-query-db-select-or-entityfieldquery). Moreover (2) I changed the [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) with the [field_attach_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) since there is no need to save the whole node ([ref](https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/10/24/saving-nodes-fields-without-saving-node-itself)).

From [drupal.org](http://drupal.org): [Static queries](https://www.drupal.org/node/310072) vs [Dynamic queries](https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries)

I hope that helps!

Comment: tnx for your attention, but I just need compare between 2 method( I know I can do them with better solution)

Comment: Two notes.  In general queries against the node table should be an EFQ or `db_select('node')->addTag('node_access')` to prevent any access bypass problems.  However, there are cases where `db_query` is OK (eg, admin only touchup scripts).  And, the node hooks don't fire and the node access tables don't get updated with `field_attach_update`.  Again, this may or may not be a problem, depending on the situation.  If you have grants that use the term data, then it is a problem and would require a manual permission rebuild.

Comment: Thus would be the fastest, and may only take a few seconds at worst only. However, as MPD mentioned node access and grants, you will need to rebuild permissions. Furthermore, taxonomy module implements node_update hook to update its index, which field_update_* isn't doing. You'll have to manually rebuild taxonomy index at least.

Comment: I thought that the question was about performance on how to update a node's field, possibly through a script. I didn't knew that `node access`, grants, rebuild permissions and indexes also had to be updated,I guess it depends on the use case like MPD said. Frankly, I didn't even knew that `field_attach_update` don't updates those things.Still I learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @zhilevan This code (if you don't know already) is a reliable execution time measurement: `$mtime = microtime();
  $mtime = explode(" ", $mtime);
  $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
  $starttime = $mtime;  // Code goes here $mtime = microtime();
  $mtime = explode(" ", $mtime);
  $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
  $endtime = $mtime;
  $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);` Perhaps will help!

Comment: I know it ,tnx for your mention,;)

Comment: @mchar Your code can be simplified like that `$starttime = microtime(TRUE); /* Your code here */ $totaltime = microtime(TRUE) - $starttime;` Secondly, there are already timer functions in Drupal: `timer_start("mytimer"); /* Your code here */ $totaltime = timer_read("mytimer");`