# How to select fields from content type

Tags: entities, nodes, database

What is the best way to do a db query for fields in a content type?

I need to get specific fields from a content type, but only where the 'featured' field value is 1.

```
<?php
        $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

        $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mycontenttype')
          ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
          ->fieldCondition('field_mypdf', 'value', 'NULL', '!=')
          ->fieldCondition('field_mypdf', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
          ->fieldCondition('field_mypdf_image', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
    ?>
```

Originally, I was doing something along the lines of:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT node.nid AS nid, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_date_text_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_teaser_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_body_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_video_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_video_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_mypdf_node_entity_type
    FROM node
    INNER JOIN field_data_field_news_is_featured ON node.nid = field_data_field_news_is_featured.entity_id AND (field_data_field_news_is_featured.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_news_is_featured.deleted = '0')";
?>

$result = db_query($query);

<?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>

    <div class="featuredArticle">
        <?php print $row->field_mypdf_value; ?>
        <?php print $row->field_mypdf_fid; ?>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you not create a view adding featured as a 1 as one of the filter criteria..?

Comment: Yes, I can. The featured field is actual not the most important part. I just wanted to be sure of the best way to get the fields from content type

Comment: Views module does this.

Answer (score 1):

I think choice is in between [EntityQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) and [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) and EntityQuery seems to be a better choice for Entities as it takes care of joining different fields for you.

Reference Link: [EntityFieldQuery vs Db_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12515/entityfieldquery-vs-db-select) -

@Bart says: -

> I think that the main reason prefering EntityFieldQuery over db_select
>   is that you don't have to know about the lower-level structure, in
>   other words: how stuff is stored in the database. This improves loose
>   coupling.

@Berdir comment:-

> This is correct, although it goes even further. The field storage is
>   pluggable. The default implementation stores field data in a separate
>   table per field in the database, but it can be replaced, there is for
>   example an implementation which allows to store field data in MongoDB.
>   If you want your code to be portable and not just work on your
>   specific site configuration, you must use EntityFieldQuery.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I will need to loop through each row of the query ... I can do this wither either method? Also for the EntityFieldQuery, I can add additional fieldCondition? How would I do this just using a SELECT?

Comment: Also, I need to query all nodes of a given content type, not just a single node.

Comment: Please check the documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708, best would be to try it out. Your doubts will get clear. With no doubt, Entity Query is traversing through all your nodes. Yes you can add multiple fieldConditions.

Comment: http://dropbucket.org/node/54

Comment: I updated original question with my EntityFieldQuery...what am I doing wrong?